# Convert Unix Timestamp Subtraction to Hours/Minutes in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am performing a LAG operation between two unix timestamp which is working perfectly fine. However I would like to convert the resulted column in Hour/Minutes

```
df_new = df_new.withColumn("diff", F.when(F.isnull(df_new.calculated_time - df_new.prev_value), 0)
                              .otherwise(df_new.calculated_time.cast('long') - df_new.prev_value.cast('long')))
```

Output-

```
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
|         primary_key|              status|calculated_time|   prev_value|     diff|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
|{"approval_id": "...|Pending review by...|  1562315397258|         null|        0|
|{"approval_id": "...|              Denied|  1562936139570|1562315397258|620742312|
|{"approval_id": "...|Request clarifica...|  1563172343614|1562936139570|236204044|
|{"approval_id": "...|                null|  1563172473488|1563172343614|   129874|
|{"approval_id": "...|            Approved|  1563190166533|1563172473488| 17693045|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
```

In the 'diff' column I would like to have minutes instead. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: it should be in min i.e 60 (min)

Comment: why dont you just divide by 60 ? you current value is in second

Comment: Just divide by 60000. You have time in milliseconds. For instance, for the second row `calculated_time` is July 12 around 1 pm and `prev_value` is July 5th around 8:30 am. That's around 7 days + 4.5 hours difference which works out to 10350 minutes. If you take `diff` and divide by 60000 you would get `620742312/60000. = 10345.7052`.

Comment: @pault Thank you!